# Syntax error: missing `closing parenthesis` MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

> I don't know way I got this error message here:

[image]

**Here is the query:**

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.totalAvg, ABS(`average for this subject`-totalAvg)  AS Difference, 100*MIN(`average for this subject`,totalAvg)/MAX(`average for this subject`,totalAvg) AS precent
FROM (SELECT StudentFirstName,StudentLastName,ClassName,AVG(Grade) AS `average for this subject`
      FROM tests
      INNER JOIN students ON tests.StudentID=students.StudentID
      GROUP BY StudentFirstName,StudentLastName,ClassName
     ) t1
JOIN (SELECT StudentFirstName,StudentLastName,AVG(`average for this subject`) as totalAvg
      FROM (SELECT StudentFirstName,StudentLastName,ClassName,AVG(Grade) AS `average for this subject`
            FROM tests
            INNER JOIN students ON tests.StudentID=students.StudentID
            GROUP BY StudentFirstName,StudentLastName,ClassName
           ) t
      GROUP BY StudentFirstName,StudentLastName
     ) t2 
ON t1.StudentFirstName=t2.StudentFirstName and t1.StudentLastName=t2.StudentLastName
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code may have other errors, but this is definitely incorrect in MySQL:

```
MIN(`average for this subject`, totalAvg)
```

`MIN()` only takes one argument.  Presumably, you want `LEAST()`:

```
LEAST(`average for this subject`, totalAvg)
```

Comment: And what about the `MAX` ?

Comment: @Error404 . . . The `MAX()` would have the same problem.  You probably want `GREATEST()`.